# Child_info_fork error running code on cygwin

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I'm using NetBeans and I use Cygwin as the compiler but I'm constantly getting an error, running a simple code like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf('a');
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error :

```
2 [main] make 8400 child_info_fork::abort: C:\cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x610000) != child(0x2F0000)
make: nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk:33: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
2 [main] make 9712 child_info_fork::abort: C:\cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x610000) != child(0x430000)
make: vfork: Resource temporarily unavailable

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 139ms)
```

Comment: That's not how you use `printf`. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Comment: Thanks chris.. But I think thats not because of Printf.. since I get a same error on a code like this :

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int a =2 ;
return 0;
}

Comment: A quick search found this: http://cygwin.wikia.com/wiki/Rebaseall, from [a cygwin question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9300722/422353)

Comment: did you try to clean & build?
reinstallation of cygwin might help: not for everyone it works but for some works

Comment: Thanks madth .. that actually helped me... The problem was because of the antivirus I recently installed.. thanks again ;)