# cygwin error with exit code -1073741819

Tags: cygwin

A cygwin 32-bit version installed on windows 7 64-bit has worked well for a few years. Lately it started to have a lot more errors with fork problem. An example is like:

```
+ cnt=44
+ '[' 44 -le 50 ']'
     40 [main] bash 3348 fork: child -1 - forked process 4248 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code -1073741819, errno 11
./testsh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
++ printf %03d 44
```

The example is by running this script:

```
$ cat testsh
#!/bin/bash -x
cnt=0
while [ $cnt -le 50 ]; do
    echo $( printf "%03d" $cnt )
    cnt=$(($cnt + 1))
done
```

Any idea about the specific cause?

Since cygwin has been installed long ago and working well, it cannot be updated. I know it might be better to re-install a late version, but the question is what caused the problem?

Comment: Generally, this is a rebaseall issue. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14509551/1549185

Comment: A great link! Will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer.

As I said above, this error usually indicates that you need to do a rebaseall.

See Here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14509551/1549185

Comment: it works! thanks a lot. another solution is to prepend yagarto tools path before cygwin path thus it uses sh, cp, and make from yagarto than cygwin therefore to avoid the problem. it still puzzles me why all of a sudden it happens a lot while I have not installed new packages for a long time.