# cygwin dash and rebase installation

Tags: bash, cygwin

How do I add the dash.exe and rebase packages discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300722/cygwin-error-bash-fork-retry-resource-temporarily-unavailable)?  I've searched around a bit and probably don't get how to add additional items well, so any comments on how you found/know the answer please shed light.  Thanks.

Here's a pic of my cygwin installer, and I'm missing the dash.exe and rebase but have ash.exe in my cygwin/bin folder.  Also, do you recommend installing bash separately (as cygwin has a pretty old version)?  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your setup.exe is out of date, I would guess.  At least in 2.871 it has a search box in the upper left.  Try downloading a new one.  It also accepts [command line arguments](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.cli)

Comment: I'd also recommend trying a different mirror, because Cygwin's bash is up-to-date (4.3)

Comment: Thanks Pak, I appreciate it.  For some reason the cygwin company version given here is far out of date.  I thought it was recent.  Apparently the uname-r command shows the version.  I appreciate your help.